Animate multiple material transitions smoothly
I have a lipstick that i want to animate into different materials. My animation is working but the color of the lipstick is not the real color and it's mixed between them. I want to use the actual color. This is the example of my animation with 3 color. First color is blue, then yellow, and red. But the second color appear to be purple not yellow

And here's my node. I use 2 mix shader. One shader for two colors and second is for the mix from two and last color

I also use texture coordinate to use empty object to animate the transition


If the 3 materials are the same (except the color), you can keep only one Principled BSDF, and plug as color a Color Ramp with the 3 colors you want instead of black&white. It will simplify your nodes quite a bit (like half of it).

Arguably, having 3 materials make no sense if it's the same material with only the color changing.

@Lutzi thank you for your suggestion. I already implement it for 2 colors. But i'm confused to use it with 3 colors bcs i use empty object as texture coordinate to help the transition. I updated my question. Should i differentiate it?

You could mix 2 colors with a Gradient (on Z) and Noise texture as factors, then mix with a third color with the same setup. To move the colors, keyframe the location values of the Mapping nodes:


If you mix two colors, the result will be a combination of the two, what you want instead is a boolean value (one color or another):
you can obtain this with math node like "Greater than".
I mixed 3 colors, but the method works for mixing shaders also.


les grands esprits se rencontrent as we say in french   ;)

Always funny when in parrallel :)
